# http GET on iOs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Im trying to get answer (an image) from a service on a PC with a HTTP GET request.
If I put the request into a webbrowser, I get the requested image. If I try to get it in iPhone app, it doesnt work.

the request is:

```
http://192.168.151.82:54000/snapshot?s=<snapshotrequest xmlns=\"http://www.vizrt.com/snapshotrequest\"><videomoderequest><width>880</width><height>495</height></videomoderequest><snapshotdata view=\"all\"/></snapshotrequest>&p=http://192.168.151.82:8580/element_collection/storage/shows/%%257B3646FFAC-4E77-41AB-BDFC-F581D157ABA3%%257D/elements/1000/
```

my code for getting is:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.168.151.82:54000/snapshot?s=<snapshotrequest xmlns=\"http://www.vizrt.com/snapshotrequest\"><videomoderequest><width>880</width><height>495</height></videomoderequest><snapshotdata view=\"all\"/></snapshotrequest>&p=http://192.168.151.82:8580/element_collection/storage/shows/%%257B3646FFAC-4E77-41AB-BDFC-F581D157ABA3%%257D/elements/1000/"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
UIImage *img = [ [ UIImage alloc ] initWithData: [ NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url ] ];
```

You can see, that speciel characters like quotes and percentes are handeled.
Im watching network communication on the PC with wireshark and there isn't any communication.

Comment: 192.168.151.82:54000 is accessable from the outside? Looks like a local ip address, which the iphone cannot reach.

Comment: I agree with prine.  Make sure you are going over wireless and that the firewall on the PC is not blocking the request.

Comment: Everything is OK with the network, with IP and with firewall. I can request the image from my mac in the web-browser.

Comment: As @JohnKoerner said, are you sure your iPhone is connected on WiFi to the same network as your mac and PC and NOT running on 3G? Try using mobile safari in the iPhone to access the URL and see if there is any network communication

Comment: can you see the image inside safari on the iPhone, if you navigate to that url ?

Comment: I CAN see the image in safari in simulator! ( i copied the request from the app and i got the image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to url encode your parameters before creating a url from them

```
NSString * unencodeParameter = @"<snapshotrequest xmlns=\"http://www.vizrt.com/snapshotrequest\"><videomoderequest><width>880</width><height>495</height></videomoderequest><snapshotdata view=\"all\"/></snapshotrequest>&p=http://192.168.151.82:8580/element_collection/storage/shows/%%257B3646FFAC-4E77-41AB-BDFC-F581D157ABA3%%257D/elements/1000/";

NSString * encodedParameter = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
            NULL,
            (CFStringRef)unencodedParameter,
            NULL,
            (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
            kCFStringEncodingUTF8 );

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://192.168.151.82:54000/snapshot?s=%@",encodedParameter];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
UIImage *img = [ [ UIImage alloc ] initWithData: [ NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url ] ];
```

And also make sure your iPhone is on same wifi as your computer as you are using local IP address

Comment: finally I can see the communication, but the server returns this error:

<error xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" type="Insufficient data" code="InsufficientData">
<description>
Not enough data was provided to allow PreviewServer to decide scene to render. Both payload and scene arguments to snapshotservice were null/empty.
</description>
</error>

Comment: Thank you Saurabh! I had to delete characters: "=" and "&" from percentescapes and it is working! So I have now (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@+$,/?%#[]"